# Select From a Table Where the column value does not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  Id, Name, Lastname
FROM customers AS c, Places AS p, 
WHERE c.customer_ID = p.customer_ID
```

My problem is that, i want to prevent the result of the query of showing a row that exist in another table(stages)

Comment: sorry for the title, i wanted to say IF EXIST

Comment: Use either an `IF NOT EXISTS()` construct, or `LEFT JOIN that other table ON your on clause WHERE some non-nullable column in other table IS NULL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a LEFT JOIN and check for null.

```
SELECT  Id, Name, Lastname
FROM customers AS c LEFT JOIN Places AS p ON c.customer_ID = p.customer_ID
WHERE p.customer_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
and not exists
(subquery to select your exclusions)
```

to your query

Comment: hey again!! sorry i'm a newbe . the result was the opposite, i want the prevent the result of the query of showing that row, if exists to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT  Id, Name, Lastname
FROM customers AS c JOIN Places AS p USING(customer_ID)
```

This is faster way that you could make with `in/exists`.

Comment: Does MySQL support the using keyword?

Comment: What keyword did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

`SELECT  Id, Name, Lastname
FROM customers, 
WHERE customer_ID NOT IN (SELECT customer_ID FROM Places)`

Comment: For large datasets, not in is very slow.

Comment: You are right. Thinking about it again, it is clear NOT EXISTS must be faster. It can stop when one record is found, whereas mine should check all the records in the NOT IN (...) part.